# What is a water blank?

Tags: water

What is a water blank?

I am doing some research and I am suppose to prepare a solution. I should mix 10g of soil with 95ml of water blank in order to create a soil suspension.

My problem is I am not English and I have no idea what a water blank is. I have a feeling the type of water is pretty important here though. (can't find what it is on the internet).

Help please. A simple definition/description will do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally a blank means no sample and just solution. So it would not contain the 10g of soil in this case. I think for soil analysis it's used as a control so you can have something to compare to.

Here's some links I found by doing an internet search.
http://asl.irri.org/lims/index.jsp?page=about&feature=soilanalysis

http://www.soiltest.vt.edu/PDF/lab-procedures.pdf

Comment: Thanks. I'm basically just trying to isolate some microorganisms from the soil in order to then incubate them, so they grow on a solid medium (BHI agar). And I don't want to kill them off by accident or do something wrong.